# Firebase redirect user to a new URL when they enter my website

Tags: firebase, next.js, vercel

I had previously hosted my website on firebase on this URL: https://oldurl.firebaseapp.com/
and that application is outdated.

Recently I have updated the application and decided to try out Vercel and created an instance of my website on this URL:  https://newurl.now.sh/

Now I don't want the user to go to that previous firebase domain and view that outdated application. What I want is to redirect the user from the firebase domain to the new Vercel domain.

Suppose when the user goes to this URL https://oldurl.firebaseapp.com/, I want to redirect them to this URL: https://newurl.now.sh/

How do I do that?

Comment: I have access to my firebase settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to a new URL when they enter your website, edit your project's `firebase.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build", //whatever your public directory is
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "https://mynewurl.now.sh/",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then deploy

I found this solution from a google firebase group

Further information about hosting configuration can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting. Rewrites (like the code snippet) are covered in the [Configure redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) section.

Comment: I'd add that all of this is covered on the Firebase Documentation, specifically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects

Comment: does this work for other routes like /**?id=foo ?